# Translating an EER diagram supertype into a database schema

Tags: database-schema, entity-relationship

How would you go about turning a supertype with two subtypes into a database schema? If I have the supertype person with two subtypes, student and staff, how would this translate into a database schema? (They would all have an ID, name, and email address).

Answer (score 0):

I would make a table called person because if you would make a table called stundent and staff what would you do if a student is a staff at the same time?
then your database would become redundant. so just make a table called person and then just assign the students to the classes and the staff to there department.